# loadData= "LOAD DATA ' %s ' INTO TABLE %s " %finalpath %tblname TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, pymysql, mysql-connector-python

I have 2 variables `finalpath` and `tblname`. The variable `finalpath` contains the name of the text files from where we load data and `tblname` contains the name of tables in which we load data from `finalpath`. I am using python connector to run my SQL queries.

When I try to load data from a single file using the following line of code

```
loadData= "LOAD  DATA INFILE '/mnt/Wdrive/pc70/SK/E07/CM_lad_19Dez2018_14Uhr38.txt' into TABLE CM_lad_19Dez2018_14Uhr38"
```

It successfully reads the text file from the path given and loads the corresponding data into the table  `CM_lad_19Dez2018_14Uhr38`
This is true in the case of 1 file. 
Now the problem is, I have 100's of 1000's of files in the path `/mnt/Wdrive/pc70/SK/E07/`. I want to create the tables which correspond to the name of the files and then to load data into their corresponding tables. 
I have successfully created the tables using the following code:

```
    rootDir = '/mnt/Wdrive/pc70/SK/E07'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
        for fname in fileList:
                tblname = os.path.basename(fname).split('.')[0]
                print(tblname)
                sql= 'CREATE TABLE %s (Datum varchar(12), Uhrzeit varchar(13), UpsACT_V varchar(6), UpsPRE_V varchar(6), IpsACT_A varchar(6),IpsPRE_A varchar(6), PpsACT_W varchar(6), PpsPRE_W varchar(10))' %tblname
                myCursor.execute(sql)
                myConnection.commit()
```

Based on the `CREATE TABLE` query, I created a query for `LOAD DATA` which is as follows

```
loadData= "LOAD DATA ' %s ' INTO TABLE %s " %finalpath %tblname
```

My code exits with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "25createtable.py", line 41, in <module>
loadData= "LOAD DATA ' %s ' INTO TABLE %s " %finalpath %tblname
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I have tried many other combinations for `LOAD DATA` but with no success

```
loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s[..]' INTO TABLE %s [..]" %finalpath % tblname
loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE [..] INTO TABLE %s [..]" % tblname
```

Is there any possible solution to this? 
Looking forward to the feedback

Comment: If you are going to end up with thousands of tables, you will have other problems.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your reply. Can you please list couple of problems to give  me an idea of what kind of problems should I expect??

Comment: Hassles collecting data from multiple tables; performance degradation.  Depending on what you are doing, it _may_ be practical to `LOAD DATA` into a staging table, then copy into the one big table.

Comment: `loadData= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '%s' " %finalpath + "INTO TABLE %s" %tblname`
This format of query worked for me where finalpath and table names are variables and their content is coming from the actual folder names and the files present in it.
I hope it might be helpful for someone else as well.
Thanks :)